# quaternion weighted average filter using color images in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, quaternions, weighted-average

In here I want to input color image, then extract rgb color spaces and divide these rgb color pixels in to 3-by-3 submatrices, then also I want to calculate pixel distance by using intensity and chromaticity differences simultaneously. Then again I want to get Euclidean distance as a weight by using this distance. Finally, I want to get Quaternion weighted average filter(QWAF) by using the weight I found above. To get QWAF here is the formula. `QWAF=summation(wi*qi)/summation(wi)` where `i` stands for pixel from filtering window and `i` starts from 1 to 9, `wi` is weigt calculated in above, `qi` is quaternion form of color image. This will be applied for full color image of all submatrices. Then finally I want to get new processed image from QWAF and display this new color image.

```
I = imread('Im.png');
I=double(imresize(I,[277,277]));
d=3;
[x,y]=size(f);
m=floor(x/d);
n=floor(y/d);
m_rest=mod(x,d);
n_rest=mod(y,d);
%remove rows and columns that will not fit
new_f=f(1:(end-m_rest),1:(end-n_rest));
%create matrix with (m,n) pages
new_f=reshape(new_f,[d m d n]);
new_f=permute(new_f,[1 3 2 4]);
w1=1/(sqrt(sum(((new_f(:,:,1,:))-(new_f(:,:,5,:))) .^ 2)));% calculating euclidean distance
w2=1/(sqrt(sum(((new_f(:,:,2,:))-(new_f(:,:,5,:))) .^ 2)));
.
.
.
w90=1/(sqrt(sum(((new_f(:,:,90,:))-(new_f(:,:,86,:))) .^ 2)));
QWAF1=((new_f(:,:,1,:)).*(w1));%Quaternion calculation,Q(x,y)
QWAF2=((new_f(:,:,2,:)).*(w2));
.
.
.
QWAF9=((new_f(:,:,9,:)).*(w9));
Quat1_9=cat(9,...
QWAF1,QWAF2,QWAF3,QWAF4,QWAF5,QWAF6,QWAF7,QWAF8,QWAF9);
.
.
.
Quat_total=cat(10,QWAF1_9,QWAF10_18,QWAF19_27,QWAF28_36,QWAF37_45,QWAF46_54,QWAF55_63,QWAF64_72,QWAF73_81,QWAF82_90);
```

Finally, when I want to display `Quat_total` as full image, it doesn't give me the right image. Any help, please?

Comment: Please structure and clarify your question. We cannot run the code as you presented, as we do not have the inputs (think up sample ones) and there are a lot of dots, generating invalid syntax. Please see [mcve]. Stack Overflow is a *question* and answer site, and you haven't asked a question, just stated "It doesn't give the right image". What does it do instead? Give the left image? Generate an error? Make your computer explode? Please be more clear.

Comment: when I try to display imshow(Qaut_total) at last line  and imshow(new_f) at line 14, it gives me this error:    Error using images.internal.imageDisplayValidateParams>validateCData (line 115)
Multi-plane image inputs must be RGB images of size MxNx3.